# Multiple Presentation Layers over single service

Tags: rest, graph, graphql, architecture, api-design

The question is pretty straightforward, **is it possible to have multiple presentation layers working on the same service**? E.g: have a REST API for applications that mostly do CRUD operations with the data and a Graph API for clients that would benefit from fetching data according to their needs. The inspiration for this question comes from a diagram (below) that appears in the docs of GraphQL.

[image: GraphQL architecture diagram]

In this diagram the Presentation Layer takes whatever form while using the same Business Layer and subsequently the same Data Access Layer. While I assume this is usual (I might be wrong), I haven't found any resources on the internet explaining what is common practice.

I am currently trying to build a Graph and a REST within the same application, I don't know if this is industry standard or it would be to have each Presentation Layer access another service thus having three separate applications (one packaging business layer + data access layer and one for each presentation layer).

It is worth mentioning that I haven't worked with GraphQL previously (only REST APIs) and there might be some kind of obvious impediment that I do not know about.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm thinking about such questions I usually try to find out either "reference architecture" for my tech stack or discover how other companies solve similar problems.

E.g. I for examples of well defined API I usually refer to GitHub API. GitHub has both REST and GraphQL API. I can assume that resources exposed via both API are the same - branches, pull requests, commits etc.
In you app you probably also have some data/entities exposed via API. I can imagine at least those will be the same and you can reuse them.
Probably it would be interesting for you check our their migration guide https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/migrating-from-rest-to-graphql
They say :

> The differences between REST as a style and GraphQL as a specification make it difficult—and often undesirable—to replace REST API calls with GraphQL API queries on a one-to-one basis

At this point it seems that having 3 different applications which sharing same data models for every Presentation Layer is an option.

Then let's check "reference architecture". I'm from .net world and for me it's
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers#net-microservices-sample-reference-application.
If I look in Ordering microservice I see that it has both REST and GRPC API provided :

[Orderting API][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkAS8.png

That's achieved by structuring application using Clean Architecture approach. For my .net stack pretty good intro is given here, but the concept is applied for any programming language:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture
The core idea is following :

> Clean architecture puts the business logic and application model at
> the center of the application. Instead of having business logic depend
> on data access or other infrastructure concerns, this dependency is
> inverted: infrastructure and implementation details depend on the
> Application Core. This functionality is achieved by defining
> abstractions, or interfaces, in the Application Core, which are then
> implemented by types defined in the Infrastructure layer.

To sum up I would say following:

- you don't need to have 3 separate application for every Presentation layer
- define interfaces in the Business Logic layer and make Presentation depend on interfaces
- it could be that e.g. for REST and GraphQL you might need sometimes different interfaces defined because the whole concept of accessing data is different
- even if you have different interface they operate with same data models defined in your Business Logic layer(Core)
- it quite possible that different interfaces implementation (e.g. let's call them RestQueryService and GraphQlQuery Service) will use same interfaces of your Persistence layer.

Comment: Thank you for such a well-documented answer and the guidelines. Since I posted the question I've dug a little deeper and I've met with some of the differences you have mentioned between the two specifications. Anyway, I will read carefully the resources you have provided and will mark as accepted answer if no doubts remain.

Comment: I'm really glad it's useful for your. If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask)